How to read DEVID register properly using SPI Protocol for AVR16A?
I am trying to read DEVID register from ADXL345 sensor using SPI protocol but always print 0x00 instead of 0xE5.but i don't know what the problem is. Is this firmware side problem or Hardware side?

#define F_CPU 8000000UL

#include <stdio.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>


void USART_Init() {
    UBRRL = 51;
    UCSRB = (1 << RXEN) | (1 << TXEN);

    UCSRC = (1 << URSEL) | (1 << UCSZ1) | (1 << UCSZ0);
}

void USART_Transmit(char data) {
    while (!(UCSRA & (1 << UDRE)));
    UDR = data;
}

void USART_msg(const char *msg) {
    while (*msg) {
        USART_Transmit(*msg++);
    }
}

void InitSPI()
{
    DDRB |= (1 << PB5) | (1 << PB7) | (1<<PB4);
    DDRB &= ~(1 << PB6);
    SPCR = (1 << SPE) | (1 << MSTR) | (1<<CPOL) | (1<<CPHA) | (1 << SPR0);
}

char WriteByteSPI(char cReg, char cData)
{
    PORTB &= ~(1 << PB4);
    SPDR = cReg;
    while (!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)));
    SPDR = cData;
    while (!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)));
    PORTB |= (1 << PB4);
    return SPDR;
}

char ReadByteSPI(char cReg)
{
    return WriteByteSPI(cReg | 0x80, 0xAA);
}

int main() {
    USART_Init();
    InitSPI();

    WriteByteSPI(0x2D, 0x08);
    WriteByteSPI(0x31, 0x08);
    int data = ReadByteSPI(0x00);
    char buffer[50];

    while (1) {
        sprintf(buffer, "DEVID_Reg:0x%02X  \r\n", data);
        for(int i=0;buffer[i] != '\0';i++)
        {
        USART_msg(buffer);
        }
        _delay_ms(200);
    }

    return 0;
}

~   


Please read page 15 of ADXL345 datasheet to understand how many bytes you need to clock to read the data, and take a look at this example.
